# opencv 3.1 installation and BaseFilter class

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I tried compiling and installing opencv 3.1 on my Ubuntu box. After the installation I was trying to create a custom filter using the `cv::BaseFilter` class. But I cannot find the necessary include file for that. Right now I'm including `<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>`. I noticed that there is `filterengine.hpp` in the source files used for opencv compilation, but I cannot find the same file in the `/usr/local/include/opencv2` installation directory. Is this the right include? If yes, how can I install after compilation? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can reach this class in OpenCV 3.1
What kind of filter would you like to define?

Comment: @Kornel see the comments to the answer from http://answers.opencv.org/question/102420/opencv-31-installation-and-basefilter-class/

Answer (score 1):

The filtering classes were made private in OpenCV 3.1. As a workaround one can add `CV_EXPORTS` to class definitions in `modules/imgproc/src/filterengine.hpp` (e.g.,  `class CV_EXPORTS BaseRowFilter`) then compile/install openCV from scratch again. After that, copy the same `filterengine.hpp` to your project and include it. Everything should compile and link fine from that point. In the default case without `CV_EXPORTS` those classes are not made external in the output openCV shared libs.